# ISODate PHP and MongoDB issues

Tags: php, mongodb, date, php-mongodb

I am trying to show the date on my website and it is not working with the following

```
<? print date('Y-M-d h:i:s', $content['date']);?>
```

when I print it out

```
<?=$content['date'];?>
```

I get the following  0.89700000 655899

I have looked into mongoDB and rockmongo and it shows it saved as  `"date": ISODate("2014-11-01T04:04:08.708Z"),`

Comment: Can you used `print date('Y-M-d h:i:s', strtotime($content['date']));` ???

Answer (score 1):

Well yes. The [MongoDate](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodate.php) object is actually broken into "seconds" and "microseconds" within the object. e.g:

```
MongoDate Object ( [sec] => 1346300336 [usec] => 593000 )
```

So you just want something like this on the 'seconds' accessor:

```
date('Y-M-d h:i:s', $content['date']->sec);
```